# Protect files from copying and reading Linux

Tags: linux, security

due to audit requirements, I need to protect all elasticsearch data files from being copied and read to another location (for example, the case when a hacker entered my server via ssh and downloaded files via rsync), as far as I understand, here I need to select file-system encryption (like ecryptfs ) because if I choose disk encryption LUKS+dm_crypt it won't help me protect these files from copying (because disk based encryption only protects files when the disk is offline)

so what the solution should i choose to protect my files from reading after it will copy to another location?

Comment: filesystem encryption will not protect you from the scenario you describe, because if the hacker manages to ssh in and get root privileges he can access all data because the filesystem *has to be decrypted while mounted or it can't be used*.

Comment: The question might be better asked over at [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that may help in the scenario you describe (hacker gains ssh access and sufficient privileges to read and copy data files) would be for elasticsearch to

1. encrypt its data at rest (IE, when written to the filesystem), and
2. **For the key to said encrypted data not to be in a config file on that same system**.

The first one is *relatively* trivial to implement; the second is much, much harder than I make it sound.

Filesystem encryption will not protect you in this scenario any further than disk encryption did.